# Correct subsection bookmarks without section

Tags: hyperref, pdf, bookmarks

I have a bunch of "naked" subsections, i.e. not belonging to a section.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
  \usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}
  \usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{hyperref}
  \hypersetup{unicode=true,
              pdfborder={0 0 0},
              breaklinks=true}
  \urlstyle{same}
\begin{document}
\chapter{First}
\subsection{Foo}
\subsection{Bar}
\subsection{Fizz}
\subsection{Buzz}

\chapter{Second}
\section{Sect}
\subsection{Foo}
\subsection{Bar}
\subsection{Fizz}
\subsection{Buzz}
\end{document}
```

The bookmark to the first subsection upgrades to a section bookmark, and all the rest subsection bookmarks seem to belong to this.

[image]

In the second chapter, with a section present, everything works OK. How can I have the subsection under the chapter, like this?

[image]

Comment: Loading the [`bookmark`](https://ctan.org/pkg/bookmark) package might do the job.

Comment: Perfect! Just as simple as that! Please submit this as an answer, to accept it.

Comment: A subsection without parental section is no subsection and a logically and typographically ill designed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`bookmark`](https://ctan.org/pkg/bookmark) package should fit your requirements. From the manual:

> In the same way as `hyperref` the bookmarks are generated in the order of the bookmark generating macros (`\bookmark`). A level number is used to define the tree structure of the bookmarks. The restrictions are less strict:
>
> - The level values may jump and omit values. A `\subsubsection` may follow
>     a `\chapter`. This was an error in `hyperref`, that prints a warning and tries to fix this.